# How to integrate a function of $y$ over a polygon

Tags: integration

I am given the coordinates of the vertices of a polygon and I need to integrate a function of $f$ (shown in the picture) to solve my problem. How can I do it? Btw. I will use it in a software which I am developing as a term project. So, I am looking for a programmable solution

[image]

Comment: Do you want me to write $f(y)$ in the question for you? If so is it $\alpha$ after $=$ sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of Green's theorem.  What is interesting is that the function you are integrating is a function of $y$ only.  So when you examine the form of Green's theorem

$$\iint_D \left ( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right ) dx \, dy = \oint_{\partial D} (P dx + Q dy)$$

where $D$ is the polygon, then clearly $\partial Q/\partial x = 0$.  Clearly we are left with

$$- \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = f(y)$$

so that, within a constant

$$P(y) = -a \frac{y^2}{b} + a \frac{y^3}{3 b^2}$$

We still do not know $Q$ except that it too must be a function of $y$.  It turns out that this is not important because we are integrating about a closed loop, so ultimately its contribution is zero; thus, we may as well set $Q=0$.  We are then left with the following integral:

$$ \oint_{\partial D} P(y) dx$$

as the integral sought.  To evaluate, simply parametrize each segment of the polygon as some line $y(x) = a x+b$ and integrate accordingly.  The integral will be zero along vertical segments.

Comment: I am an engineering student. It has been 3 years since I took the calculus course and I completely forgot about green's theorem. I know It's a shame but this is the first time I need it. thx :)